# Who is the BSurfaces author Eclectiel L

Tags: add-on

Anyone knows who is Eclectiel L, the mysterious main author of BSurfaces?

I've contacted him twice by email, but I get no answers. On Vimeo, he seems to be another anonymous user "Blend Ideas" https://vimeo.com/user572057

His last commit to Bsurfaces was in 2012. Is there a way to get a hold of him that you know? Otherwise, I wonder how do the developers plan to maintain the nitty-gritty details of BSurfaces in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

The [bsurfaces addon](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/mesh_bsurfaces.py) is an official blender addon. Any bug reports can be submitted to the [official blender bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/). Any patches for fixes or improvements can also be submitted to the bug tracker.

For ideas for features that you would like added, this also falls into the same category as any blender improvements, which is mostly find someone interested in doing the change. If the original author doesn't respond to contact then you need to find another developer that is interested. [RightClickSelect](https://rightclickselect.com) was started for this purpose, you can try submitting ideas there.

If you haven't seen it, you may also want to look at CGCookies [RetopoFlow addon](https://blendermarket.com/products/retopoflow), it expands on the bsurfaces idea. While it is a paid addon, it is available from it's [github repo](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow) if you want to get it free or to assist in development and bug reports.

Comment: thank you. upvoted as it is very useful, but not marked as answer as it is too generic and not a definitive answer.